# Uploading files from device using ionic just not working

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple html code, which hits my php file on my server and files are uploaded. I need to use the same thing in ionic, but it doesnt work. Below is my `home.html` code

```
<form action="http://example.com/del/uploadtest/upload3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

I tried `file chooser,file transfer` of ionic but I failed to implement it. I also tried `valor's ng upload`, it works but it only allows to send pics from device, where as from browser it allows every kind of file.

I want to upload any kind of file from Android to server.

I am unable to understand the file chooser, file transfer code and unable to find a ready to use code.

Comment: Worth checking out, this [example](https://www.djamware.com/post/599da16580aca768e4d2b130/how-to-upload-file-on-ionic-3-using-native-file-transfer-plugin) and the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/)

Comment: i tried this but did not work for me, if it works for you then i can provide you my upload url, most of it this line is so confusing `this.imageFileName = "http://192.168.0.7:8080/static/images/ionicfile.jpg"`

Comment: This sounds like a software recommendation question, which would be off-topic. It is worth remembering that often solutions do not involve "ready to use code", and you just have to write some code (or pay someone else to).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/), firstly.. install File Transfer and File plugins.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer
```

and

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

For the upload method, say it is on the HomePage

**home.html**

```
<input (click)="uploadFile()" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

**home.ts**

```
uploadFile() {
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'ionicfile',
    fileName: 'ionicfile',
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    headers: {}
  }

  fileTransfer.upload('<file path>', '<api endpoint>', options)
    .then((data) => {
    console.log(data + "Uploaded Successfully");
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Note:

`<api endpoint>` is URL of the server to receive the file, as encoded by encodeURI().

`<file path>` is Filesystem URL representing the file on the device or a data URI. For backwards compatibility, this can also be the full path of the file on the device.

In your case, your `<api endpoint>` is `http://example.com/del/uploadtest/upload3.php`

and `<file path>` is `http://192.168.0.7:8080/static/images/ionicfile.jpg`

Hope this will help!

Comment: but file path shouldn't be dynamic, i mean the path of the file i will select ? , and will this support all kind of files or just images ?

Comment: What kind of file are you uploading?

Comment: mp4,docx,pdf or excel

Comment: I see, you didn't mention it earlier! Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346710/ionic-2-uploading-docs-pdf-to-server-in-forms)

Comment: I tried this aswell, but i am getting error on this too, check this thread from my collegue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343993/ionic-3-file-select-and-upload-giving-error , if you integrate it and make it to work, please do share

Answer (score 0):

This is the script the works for me!
No need to use any plugin
You can upload pdf,zip image or any file format, no need to have different plugins for android and ios 
in html

```
<input type="file" name="file"  (change)="upload($event)" />
```

in ts file

```
 upload(str:any)
  {
    const formData = new FormData();

    this.image=str.target.files[0];

    formData.append('files[]', this.image);
    console.log(formData,this.image);
    this.http.post("http://localhost/test/test.php",formData)
    .subscribe((data:any)=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
    console.log(str);
  }
```

Bonus here is the PHP file:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $path = 'uploads/';
        $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];

        $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);  
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][0];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][0];
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][0])));
            $file_name = uniqid().".".$file_ext;
            $file = $path . $file_name;
            if (empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
            }
        if ($errors) print_r($errors);
    }
}
```